# Mutation Observer - addedNodes[0] is a comment

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am trying to `console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);` which returns `<!---->`.
Any idea why is it happening? I am listening to an element called `ul.chat-lines` on `www.twitch.tv/lirik/chat`

Note: it's an ember application.

This is an if statement that should parse incoming chatlines.

`chatline = 'chat-line';`

`if(mutation.addedNodes.length && mutation.addedNodes[0].classList.contains(chatline)){`

Returns: `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`

So i placed `console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);` right after

`mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);`

Which like i said, returns `<!---->`.

```
var observerConfig = {        
    childList: true,
};
```

Example chatline from `ul.chat-lines`

```
<li id="ember1645" class="message-line chat-line ember-view"><!---->  <div>
    <span class="timestamp float-left">6:24</span>
<!----><!---->    <span class="badges float-left">
<!---->    </span>
    <span style="color:#FF0000" class="from" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1646="1646">getsomelight</span><span class="colon">:</span>
        <span style="" class="message">
              No stream today?
                    </span>
<!----><!---->  </div><!----></li>
```

Comment: A comment or text node is a valid DOM node. The observed behavior is correct. Simply enumerate all items in `addedNodes` and check each item's [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) property.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see only one added node which is 0: comment but after i inspect previousSibling > nextElementSibling' i can see the element i am looking for (li#ember1614.message-line.chat-line.ember-view)

Comment: Your code "sees" only one element because it doesn't enumerate the `addedNodes` array. Also note, if the added node is not a direct descendant, you need `subtree: true` in observerConfig.